# SQL Server - INSERT throws duplicate error but the row is INSERTED

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, sql-insert

I have an INSERT statement that throws the Violation of Primary Key error but the rows is inserted into the database successfully.

`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TableName_ID'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TableName'. The duplicate key value is (ID).`

Prior to the insert statement, I check if the ID exists in the table. If it doesn't, I proceed with the **INSERT statement**.

In the table, I have a **DATETIME** column, **InsertedAt**, which equals to the time when the rows was inserted.

I have no idea why the error is thrown and would love to hear other potential causes.

Thank you.

Comment: A possible cause may be, in the same statement, you are trying to insert rows with the same key or you are trying to insert duplicate rows. I would try to get the the query and results which you are trying to insert in the same statement  into a seperate file and look for duplicates in order to comprehend the root cause.

Comment: It's a single INSERT statement.

Comment: Check for triggers on the table. Your insert may be working properly, but then a trigger is attempting to do a second operation on it causing the duplicate error.

Comment: in a single statement you can still insert multiple lines.